# How to make the div hide automatically when not selected in navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, show-hide

I already made the div show when I clicked on it on the dropdown-navbar. But I don't want to make all the divs to show. For example I clicked from the navbar to show div1, then when i clicked another div from the navbar (div2 for example) div2 will appear then div1 should now be hidden. Same goes with the other divs.

Here's my code for the dropdown-navbar.

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="icon-edit"></i><span>Manage Events</span> <b class="caret"></b></a> 
<ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
    <li><a value="mteam" href="#" onclick="show_div('spanplayers');">Manage Team Players</a>
    </li>         
    <li><a value="mschedule" href="#" onclick="show_div('spanschedule');">Manage Game Schedule</a>
    </li>         
    <li><a value="mresult" href="#" onclick="show_div('spanresult');">Manage Game Results</a>
    </li>         
</ul>
```

Here's the javascript: (What did I missed here?)

```
<script>
//Functon to show divs from the nav menu
function show_div(toShow)
{
  var show = document.getElementById(toShow);
  show.style.display = "block";  
}
 </script>
```

Here's the divs that I want to show then hide when not selected.

```
<div class="span12" id="spanplayers" style="display:none" data-pg-collapsed> 
                            <!-- /widget -->                                 
                            <div class="widget"> 
                                <div class="widget-header"> 
                                    <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> 
                                    <h3>Manage Team Players Panel</h3> 
                                </div>                                     
                                <!-- /widget-header -->                                     
                                <div class="widget-content"> 
                                    <!-- /form-content -->
                                </div>                                     
                                <!-- /widget-content -->                                     
                            </div>                                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="span12" id="spanschedule" style="display:none" data-pg-collapsed> 
                            <!-- /widget -->                                 
                            <div class="widget"> 
                                <div class="widget-header"> 
                                    <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> 
                                    <h3>Manage Game Schedule Panel</h3> 
                                </div>                                     
                                <!-- /widget-header -->                                     
                                <div class="widget-content"> 
                                    <!-- /form-content -->
                                </div>                                     
                                <!-- /widget-content -->                                     
                            </div>                                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="span12" id="spanresult" style="display:none" data-pg-collapsed> 
                            <!-- /widget -->                                 
                            <div class="widget"> 
                                <div class="widget-header"> 
                                    <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> 
                                    <h3>Manage Game Result Panel</h3> 
                                </div>                                     
                                <!-- /widget-header -->                                     
                                <div class="widget-content"> 
                                    <!-- /form-content -->
                                </div>                                     
                                <!-- /widget-content -->                                     
                            </div>                                 
                        </div>
```

[Here's the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr1jq.png)
If you can see this is the format of div containers that I want to be shown when selected in the navbar one by one not all of them. How can I hide other div containers when they are not selected.

Here's the snippet imagine that Text headers are the div containers.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MrReachRiddle/pen/KWLppx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWagmp

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="dropdown">
    Manage Events
    <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
        <li><a value="mteam" href="#" onclick="show_div('spanplayers');">Manage Team Players</a>
        </li>         
        <li><a value="mschedule" href="#" onclick="show_div('spanschedule');">Manage Game Schedule</a>
        </li>         
        <li><a value="mresult" href="#" onclick="show_div('spanresult');">Manage Game Results</a>
        </li>    
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    Manage Events
  <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
      <li><a value="mteam" href="#" onclick="show_div('spanplayers');">Manage Team Players</a>
      </li>         
      <li><a value="mschedule" href="#" onclick="show_div('spanschedule');">Manage Game Schedule</a>
      </li>         
      <li><a value="mresult" href="#" onclick="show_div('spanresult');">Manage Game Results</a>
      </li>    
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.menu > li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
 display:none;
 position: absolute;
 top:100%;
 left: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu.open {
  display: block;
}
```

JS - using jquery

```
$( ".dropdown" ).click(function() {
  $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass( "open" );
  $(".dropdown-menu", this).toggleClass( "open" );
});
$(window).click(function() {
 $(".dropdown-menu" ).removeClass( "open" );
});
$(".dropdown").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I already made that work in my formatting here. I edited my post. Check the screenshot and its description you might get what i mean.